# Loop into an array whiteout echoing a key with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've the following array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [CA] => Array
        [country] => Canada
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => BSB
                    [example] => 123456
                    [length] => 6 characters
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Account Number
                    [example] => 12345678
                    [length] => 6 to 10 characters
                )

        )
)
```

How can I loop into this array without echoing the country name `[country] => Canada` ?

Actually, I have this:

```
foreach($array['CA'] as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

But the country name is printed.

Thanks.

Comment: Add another loop inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we do like this,

```
foreach($array['CA']['country'] as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

instead,

```
foreach($array['CA'] as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```